# Prove please that inequality ; if $x\geq 0,y\geq 0,z\geq 0$ $x+y+z\geq x^2y+y^2z+z^2x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

Prove please that inequality : if
$$x\geq 0,y\geq 0,z\geq 0$$
and
$$x^2+y^2+z^2=3,$$
then
$$x+y+z\geq x^2y+y^2z+z^2x.$$

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you write what your thoughts are on the problem and include your efforts (work in progress) in this and future posts and in what context you have encountered the problem; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level.

Comment: Just using homogenizing and AM-GM equality..

Comment: Thank you very much ,I understand . I will do what I should.

Comment: @Zack Ni can you give me a little examples please?

Comment: For example: a+b+c <= a^2+b^2+c^2,abc=1,then the degree of RHS is 2 and the degree of LHS is 1 so multiply (abc)^(1/3) to the LHS then the degree of LHS become 2(i.e. a^(4/3)*b^(1/3)*c(1/3)+b^(4/3)*a^(1/3)*c(1/3)+c^(4/3)*a^(1/3)*b(1/3) <= a^2+b^2+c^2 ) , this is called homogenizing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$(x+y+z)\times(x^2+y^2+z^2)\geq (x^2y+y^2z+z^2x)\times3$([1] to homogenize)

$\Leftrightarrow x^3+x^2z+xy^2+y^3+yz^2+z^3\geq2x^2y+2xz^2+2y^2z$

By AM-GM inequality, $\frac{x^3+xy^2}{2}\geq \sqrt{x^3\times xy^2} = x^2y$[2]

In the same manner:

1. $\frac{z^3+zx^2}{2}\geq  z^2x$...(1)
2. $\frac{y^3+yz^2}{2}\geq  y^2z$...(2)
3. $\frac{x^3+xy^2}{2}\geq \sqrt{x^3\times xy^2} = x^2y$ ...(3)

Add up (1) (2) and (3), the statement

$x^3+x^2z+xy^2+y^3+yz^2+z^3\geq2x^2y+2xz^2+2y^2z$ is true.

Reference[1]:https://www.artofproblemsolving.com/articles/files/MildorfInequalities.pdf about how to homogenize. 
Reference[2]:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means about AM-GM.

Comment: I changed some inequality signs and \times some things. I think the main problem here is how familiar with MathJax. http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: @Element118 No sign works all right. because a>=b c>0 => a*c>=b*c if a,b,c is in a ordered field.

Comment: Thank you very much ,for answer...

Answer (score 2):

Using $x^2+y^2+z^2=3$ (and the fact that $3\gt0$), we have

$$\begin{align}
x+y+z\ge x^2y+y^2z+z^2x&\iff(x^2+y^2+z^2)(x+y+z)\ge3(x^2y+y^2z+z^2x)\\
&\iff (x^3+x^2y+xy^2)+(y^3+y^2z+yz^2)+(z^3+z^2x+zx^2)\ge3x^2y+3y^2z+3z^2x\\
&\iff(x^3-2x^2y+xy^2)+(y^3-2y^2z+yz^2)+(z^3-2z^2x+zx^2)\ge0\\
&\iff x(x-y)^2+y(y-z)^2+z(z-x)^2\ge0
\end{align}$$

The final inequality holds by virtue of the assumption $x,y,z\ge0$.