# Inequality from Riasat book

Tags: inequality, contest-math, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

Let $a,b,c\geq0$.
Prove $$(a+b+c)(a^2+b^2+c^2) \geq 3(a^2b+b^2c+c^2a)$$
I tried to write LHS as $((a+b)^3+(b+c)^3+(c+a)^3)/3)$ but I got nothing interesting. 
I'm pretty sure I have to use the fact that $a^3+b^3+c^3 \geq a^2b+b^2c+c^2a$ but i wouldn't know how to exploit because in the LHS i have symmetric terms but not like RHS and not how to get rid of them

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1738946/42969

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have
$$(a+b+c)(a^2+b^2+c^2) \geq 3(a^2b+b^2c+c^2a) \tag{1}$$
if and only if
$$a^3 + b^3 + c^3 + ab^2 + bc^2 + ca^2 \ge 2(a^2 b + b^2 c + c^2 a) \tag{2}$$
Written concisely, the above inequality is
$$\sum_{\text{cyc}} a^3 + \sum_{\text{cyc}} ab^2 \ge 2 \sum_{\text{cyc}} a^2b \tag{3}$$
Using the AM-GM inequality,
$$a^3 + ab^2 = a(a^2 + b^2) \ge 2a^2b \tag{4}$$
giving
$$\sum_{\text{cyc}} a^3 + \sum_{\text{cyc}} ab^2 \ge 2 \sum_{\text{cyc}} a^2b \tag{5}$$
as required.

Comment: wow thank you so much. It was enough for me to note step 4 ugh I want to die